# How to display Session values in php with dynamic html?

Tags: php, html, session

```
<?php                            
       session_start();
       echo "<b>Start Date:</b>$_SESSION['Date']<br />";
       echo "<b>Venue:</b>$_SESSION['address']<br />";
       echo "<b>Church Name: </b>$_SESSION['ChurchLead']<br />";
       echo "<b>Course Type </b>$_SESSION['coursename']<br />";
       echo "<b>Participants: </b>$_POST['NumbPart']<br />";
       echo "<b> Latitude: </b>$_SESSION['lat']<br />";
       echo "<b> Longitude: </b>$_SESSION['long']<br />";
?>
```

Is this a correct way of displaying Session values in php? I am getting blank values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ,this is not better????? simple & easy read

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
   <b>Start Date:</b><?=$_SESSION['Date'];?><br />
   <b>Venue:</b><?=$_SESSION['address'];?><br />
   <b>Church Name: </b><?=$_SESSION['ChurchLead'];?><br />
   <b>Course Type </b><?=$_SESSION['coursename'];?><br />
   <b>Participants: </b><?=$_POST['NumbPart'];?><br />
   <b> Latitude: </b><?=$_SESSION['lat'];?><br />
   <b> Longitude: </b><?=$_SESSION['long'];?><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the value from an array like that as string sub, you need to use {} around it in the string. For example:

```
echo "<b> Latitude: </b>$_SESSION['lat']<br />";
```

becomes

```
echo "<b> Latitude: </b>{$_SESSION['lat']}<br />";
```

This applies to instances where you are trying to access an array member, or accessing an object member (such as myObj->foo)

NOTE: I am operating under the assumption that your session array is completely valid.

Answer (score 0):

First, change all lines to:

```
  echo "<b>MyVar:</b>".$_SESSION['myVar']."<br />";
```

Now, unless you have set the variable `$_SESSION['MyVar']`, you'll get blank output.

Comment: While this will work, it's pointless to use " in this case since, unless disabled, " will automatically parse the string for variables.